# Possible to hide or resize inline VF page based on criteria?

Tags: lightning, console

I would like to hide a inline VF page in a console lightning case on record load.  Is it possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 7):

This feature is being delivered in Winter 18:

> ## [Make Your Lightning Pages Dynamic](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter18/release-notes/rn_forcecom_lab_dynamic_pages.htm)
>
> Now you can control when a component appears on a record page by adding filter conditions and logic to its properties. No need to add anything to your custom components. It’s all handled by the Lightning App Builder. For example, construct a filter that causes a rich text component on an opportunity page to display when the Amount is greater than $1 million.
>
> [image: Set component visibility]
>
> Component visibility filters are supported for standard components, custom components, and components from AppExchange. If you don’t define a filter, the component displays on the Lightning record page as usual. When you define one or more filters and set the filter logic for a component, the component is hidden until the filter logic criteria are met.

Relevant Idea (status still listed as `In Development`):

> ## [Dependent page layouts - data rules to show, hide, or make fields/sections req'd](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BroxAAC)
>
> There are times when it would be ideal to show different fields or sections on a page based on field data. For example, if a field for "software interest" is selected on a lead page, it would be nice if a section and/or fields related to capturing more information on "Software" is displayed. If the field is not selected, then this section and/or fields remain hidden. Allowing greater customization on the page level based on data rules would make for more manageable and targeted page layouts.